# For embedded visuals, ArcGIS Maps for Power BI is currently not supported

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, embedding, power-bi-report-server, arcgis-server

ArcGIS map is perfectly working on power bi service. But when I embed this report into my web application "For embedded visuals, ArcGIS Maps for Power BI is currently not supported." error displayed on visual. I have signed in to the map using the 21-day free trial ArcGIS online work account and limit the lat long in the map, still not working. Does anyone have any idea about this issue?

Note: My power bi service account is different from ArcGIS online account

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What is not clear in the message "*For embedded visuals, ArcGIS Maps for Power BI is currently not supported.*"? The visual clearly says that this use case is not supported. And if you check [the limitations in the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/power-bi-visualizations-arcgis#considerations-and-limitations), it clearly states it is not supported:

[image]

Comment: I am using the power bi publish-to web feature, for this one, it is available if we signed in to a valid ArcGIS account. I am currently using a trial work account for this one. For the trial account, we have access to 2 creator usertype options, still, it's showing this error. My power bi account and ArcGIS trial account are different I don't know if this thing creating an ambiguity.